# How do you write a statically typed Python function that converts a string to a parameterized type?

Tags: python, pyright, python-3.12

I would like to write a statically typed Python function that accepts a general type and a string and that returns a value of the given type, derived from the given string.  For example:

```py
>>> parse(int | None, "5")
5
>>> parse(int | None, "") is None
True
```

Here's a Python 3.12 attempt (which has a problem in the type signature since union types can't be assigned to variables of type `type`):

```py
def parse[a](x: type[a], v: str) -> a:
    if x in (bool, bool | None):
        return bool(v)
    if x in (float, float | None):
        return float(v)
    if x in (int, int | None):
        return int(v)
    if x in (str, str | None):
        return v
    raise ValueError
```

However, this code yields errors with Pyright 1.1.349:

```
error: Expression of type "bool" cannot be assigned to return type "a@parse"
error: Expression of type "float" cannot be assigned to return type "a@parse"
error: Expression of type "int" cannot be assigned to return type "a@parse"
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Why not make `x: Callable[[str], a]`, then dedupe most of the implementation?

Comment: I just want to point out that since Python 3.10 there is the [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements) statement so you avoid having to write repeatedly `x == type`

Comment: `match` has its own boilerplate issues with this kind of exact matching. The naive attempt to write `match x: case bool: ...` doesn't do what you might think it would.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd like this function to select a callable based on the type. In other words, I'd like to start with an arbitrary type and a string and have the function give me an element of the arbitrary type. To illustrate, I've updated the example in my question to handle some union types.

Comment: @chepner The reason to allow `... | None` is simply to expand the function domain. The use case I have in mind is to apply this function over the attribute types of a dataclass, which could include `... | None` types.

Comment: This has stopped making sense to me - if I call `parse(int | None, some_str)` shouldn't I _expect_ to sometimes get `None` back, not always `int` (presumably if it _can't_ be parsed as an integer)? What about `int | float` (or `float | int`, which might behave differently given precedence). This will be very complicated to solve in anything like a general way (although maybe with e.g. [`get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) you can start teasing out what's expected of each invocation).

Comment: @jonrsharpe `parse(int | None, "")` could return `None`. Whether `parse(int | float, "1")` returns `1` or `1.0` would be up to the implementation. I don't see anything here that prevents articulating a well-defined function.

Comment: Note that `int | None` isn't really a type; it's an instance of `types.UnionType`, so you really can't use `type[A]` with such a construct in the first place and expect a meaningful return type.

Comment: @chepner OK. Is there a way to type-annotate what I have in mind?

Comment: Sorry, my brain went full-Haskell and forgot you were raising an exception to indicate parse failure, rather than returning `None`. I don't have any other annotation suggestions (I myself am missing why both `mypy` and PyRight aren't allowing a specific type to be returned), but my point about `... | None` not being a valid argument, I think, stands. (Unless type checkers have some special cases hard-coded to handle `UnionType` properly.)

Comment: @chepner You're right, union types can't be assigned to parameters of type `type`. I didn't know that.

Comment: Also, as an aside, `bool(s)` is `True` for any non-empty string; it does not parse it like a Boolean literal.

Comment: I've posted an answer that is, I believe, *mostly* correct. Some improvements might be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, this is a problem of parametricity. Your function is *not* the same for every possible type `A`.

With the signature

```
def parse[A](x: type[A], v: str) -> A:
    ...
```

the type checker has no idea what `A` is, only that a value of type `A` is required. As such, the *only* way to get such a value is to call `x`. The following trivial definition would type-check:

```
def parse[A](x: type[A], v: str) -> A:
    return x()
```

Your function, however, tries to return a value of type `bool`, or type `str`, or type `int`, etc, which (statically speaking) is *distinct* from a value of type `A`, even if `A` is bound at *runtime* to `bool` or `str` or `int`. Type narrowing does not apply to a generic type.

One workaround is to pass not the type itself, but a string representing the type, and using `typing.overload` to implement ad-hoc polymorphism rather than parametric polymorphism.

```
from typing import overload, Literal


@overload
def parse(x: Literal["str"], v: str) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def parse(x: Literal["float"], v: str) -> float:
    ...

@overload
def parse(x: Literal["int"], v: str) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def parse(x: Literal["bool"], v: str) -> bool:
    ...

def parse(x, v):
    match x:
        case "str":
            return v
        case "int":
            return int(v)
        case "float":
            return float(v)
        case "bool":
            return v.lower() == "true"
        case _:
            raise ValueError



reveal_type(parse("int", "3"))
reveal_type(parse("float", "3.0"))
reveal_type(parse("bool", "True"))
reveal_type(parse("str", "foo"))

# The following is a type error, but you were going to
# raise a runtime error anyway.
reveal_type(parse("complex", "3.9"))
```

Comment: "As such, the only way to get such a value is to call `x`." Why can't a function accept a variable of a certain type (in this case `type`) but limit its definition to a subset of values belonging to that type, raising an exception for undefined subsets of the type? To raise an algebra analogy, f(x) = sqrt(x) could have domain real numbers but be undefined for negative x.

Comment: Also, random question: If you're coming from Haskell, why use uppercase type variable `A` rather than lowercase `a`?

Comment: I mostly work in Python. Syntactically, uppercase A fits better with the rest of the syntax used for type hints, but Haskell colors my perception of semantics with regards to static typing.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, that gets into a discussion about refinement types. `Literal` provides refinement-type semantics somewhat for values that actually *have* literals. (Note that `bool` is not a literal, but a name in the built-in scope bound to a particular type, so `Literal[bool]` couldn't be used with the overloaded function I suggested as a workaround.) General support for refinement types is a ways away, I think. There is an [old issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/560) requesting support for them, though.

Comment: Might want to rethink the checkmark; https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914725/1126841 works with PyRight, though not `mypy`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try changing the constructor from `bool`,`float`,`int` to just `x` in order to get around the static type check. Additionally, avoid using passing UnionTypes into your function (for reasons I will explain in the next paragraph). This implementation should suffice for your needs.

```
def parse[a](x: type[a], v: str, nullable=False) -> a|None:
    if x in (bool,float,int,str):
        if v=='' and nullable: 
            return None
        return x(v)
    raise ValueError()
```

The reason to avoid directly using UnionType is as follows: UnionType is not a subclass of type - as showcased by the below code:

```
>>> from types import UnionType
>>> UnionType.__mro__
(<class 'types.UnionType'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> # above are the base classes of UnionType
>>> t = bool|None
>>> isinstance(t,type)
False
```

Thus you should not be able to pass union types like `bool|None`, `float|None`, `int|None` or `str|None` into `x: type` in a statically typed context.

Comment: You should replace all `if`s with `if x in (bool, float, int, str):`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a more general solution. I've updated my question to include union types.

Comment: I made some edits to my initial answer to better correspond to changes in your question.

Comment: Interesting, `pyright` seems to handle the type variable much differently than `mypy`.